# Procedimiento almacenado de autogenerar código

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Quisiera saber que tengo que hacer para usar este procedimiento almacenado de autogenerar código, quisiera que al presionar un botón "Nuevo" ejecute el procedimiento sobre una cajita de texto (Estoy trabajando en C# Visual Studio).

```
CREATE or ALTER PROCEDURE SP_GENERAR_NUMERO_VENTA
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @numero   VARCHAR(10);
  SET     @numero = (SELECT LEFT(MAX(codigoVenta),1)+RIGHT('00000000'+
  CONVERT (varchar(10),RIGHT(MAX(codigoVenta),3)+1),9)
  FROM DETALLEVENTA)
  SELECT @numero AS nro_venta;
END
GO
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No entiendo cual es tu problema...

Comment: Puedes usar Dapper, para llamar el store procedure aqui hay un ejemplo de como hacerlo https://dapper-tutorial.net/stored-procedure

Comment: ¿Qué pasará cuando dos o más usuarios presionen el botón "Nuevo" sin que ninguno haya guardado?

Answer (score 1):

Algo fácil que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

```cs
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Sql;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Configuration;

public class Prueba {

  public int call_sp_test() {

    // Para esto tienes que tener en tu Web.Config configurado las cadenas de conexión. 
   //... o bien tener la conexión hecha desde antes. 

    Database database = new SqlDatabase(
      ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NOMBRE_BD"].ToString());
    DbCommand cmd = database.GetStoredProcCommand("SP_GENERAR_NUMERO_VENTA");

    try {
      return Convert.ToInt32(db.ExecuteScalar(cmd));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      throw ex;
    }
  }
}
```

> Con .NET Framework / .NET Core es "más o menos" lo mismo; puedes averiguar las similitudes y las diferencias en Google.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes llamar a un storede procedure utilizando Dapper(es un micro ORM)

1. Agregar dapper mediante nuggets:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1. Una vez instalado puedes incluirlo usando:

   ```
   using Dapper;
   ```
2. Tambien es necesario incluir:

   ```
   using System.Data.SqlClient;
   ```

Se puede instalar igual desde los nuggets, este es necesario para usar la clase `SqlConnection`

4. El codigo necesario para llamar al stored procedure es:

   ```
   var sql = "SP_GENERAR_NUMERO_VENTA";
   var connectionString = "Server=SqlServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=*****;Password=*****;Persist Security Info=False;";

   using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
   {
       var resultado = connection.Execute(sql, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
   }
   ```

Nota: El connection string se puede poner en appsettings.json, web.config, etc., pero ese es otro tema, aqui un link con mas informacion al respecto [Pregunta sobre connection string de app.config](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/b97f5106-f174-4b0a-940e-c0fd3e4473d2/utilizar-connectionstring-del-appconfig?forum=vcses#:%7E:text=Solo%20recuperar%20la%20cadena%20de%20conexion%20por%20medio,que%20le%20diste%20en%20el%20archivo%20de%20configuraci%C3%B3n.)